# UWP : Scroll to end of RichEditBox without focus

Tags: scroll, uwp, focus, richeditbox

I'm writing a UWP app with console like text area.
How can I scroll to end without using Focus. Focus is unusefull in my case becouse my app have a more then one text input. While writing to one of inputs, async changed data in RichEditBox and seted programaticaly Focus makes it impossible becouse carret is moving to richeditbox.

Comment: Please put your coding effort here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Without code it is virtually impossible to understand your question.

Comment: Do you have any updates for this topic?

Answer (score 1):

> Scroll to end of RichEditBox without focus

You could use [`ScrollIntoView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.itextrange.scrollintoview?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Text_ITextRange_ScrollIntoView_Windows_UI_Text_PointOptions_) method scroll to end without focus for  RichEditBox. For more detail please refer the following code.

```
private async void bookmarkBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string tmp = string.Empty;
    REB.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out tmp);
    REB.Document.GetRange(0, tmp.Length).ScrollIntoView(PointOptions.None);
}
```